# HTTP request is not obtained by Proximan and mitmproxy in iPhone

Tags: http, proxy, network-programming, httprequest, mitmproxy

[PROBLEM]
I cannot get HTTP requests from some app on iPhone.

[DETAIL]
I am trying to collect HTTP requests (response) on third-party app for analytics purpose.
But, I cannot get HTTP requests even though I open the app and pull down the screen to call API (by pulling down, the page is updated so i assume some kinds of API is called).
When I open the app, I can see some of the HTTP requests (which is more like firebase logging API or facebook graph API). But after that, I cannot see any HTTP requests at all.

[QUESTION]
Why even though I pull the screen, and seems calling backend side, I don't see any of requests call ?
Is this app not using HTTP requests to communicate backend ?

[What I have tried]
I used both Proximan or mitmproxy but couldn't get the HTTp requests.
For other apps, I can see the reqeusts. Only this specific app not working...

[This is when I open the app. Seems I can get requests. after this, I cannot get any requests at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv9oE.png)

Comment: If the app contains an own HTTP client it could simply ignore the proxy settings. Or it uses certificate pinning and the request fails but you don't see an error message. You could try to check the device console/log or try to use Wireshark on the network to see if there is any network activity at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask the detail about 'the app contains an own HTTP client' ? Could it ignore the proxy setting ?

Comment: yes. I don't see any error message in both Proxyman and mitmproxy.
>but you don't see an error message

Comment: If the app contains a Library with a custom HTTP client it can ignore proxy settings and directly communicate with the internet if the network allows so.

Comment: Oh there are such kind of libraries.. 
1. May I have the name of the library ? 
2. In that case, is there any way that I could check the API response the app is returning ?

Comment: I don't do much iOS development so I don't know what libraries exists but basically all common HTTP libraries using in Linux would be a candidate. You may be able to see if an http library is used as these libraries are not recognized by ATS, so ATS considers their connections as non-HTTPS even if they use HTTPS. This means the app have to define an exclusion in ATS to allow plain text communication. Also keep in mind to check the iPhone device log for error messages.